# How do I create s:Path.data, polygon coords?

Tags: apache-flex, mxml, flex-spark, fxg

I have a PNG image, the image features a shape surrounded by a transparent area:

[image: sample image]

I want to recreate this image as a path in flex mxml, something like this:

```
<s:Path data="M 0 0 L 0 100 L 100 100 L 100 0 L 0 0" />
```

How can I export the path data so that I can use this shape in Flex, is there a program that will do this for me?

Comment: Illustrator will export to fxg directly. InkScape exports to svg, which easily translates to fxg.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

My problem was that my original image was a flat file, not a path. This meant that following *@www.Flextras.com's* answer didn't work for me, the result was an FXG with an image embedded.

The process I used is as follows, I used Adobe Fireworks for this:

**1) Magic wand selection**

Select the body of the image with magic wand.

[image: Magic Wand Selection]

**2) Convert to path**

Right click -> Modify Marquee -> Convert to Path

[image: Convert To Path]

**3) Export as FXG**

File -> Export

[image: Export As FXG]

**4) Done**

Open the FXG in notepad and extract the path data.

[image: Done]

Answer (score 2):

[Illustrator will export an FXG](http://help.adobe.com/en_US/illustrator/cs/using/WS3f28b00cc50711d9814a4f8133b3babd90-8000.html), as will [Photoshop](http://helpx.adobe.com/x-productkb/multi/photoshop-fxg-extensions-required-photoshop.html).

Comment: I've just tried doing it with illustrator, but it's not working, it also exports an assets folder and then embeds the image in the FXG. My image is a flat file, but I need to convert it to a path

Comment: Never mind, I have found how to convert it to a path, it's working now.

Comment: Great; if my suggestion doesn't answer your question; please post a more detailed answer yourself.